# Is there a way to create a CMakelist.txt from a visual studio (c++) solution?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I know that is possible to create a visual studio solution from a cmake project. But I wonder if there is a program that will do it the other way around (aka create a CMakelist.txt from a visual studio solution).

Answer (score 0):

First Google hit for "sln to cmakelist": [vcproj2cmake](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcproj2cmake/)