# Generating CMakeLists.txt from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have used several C++ libraries that ship with CMakeLists.txt for building them on various platforms.  It works well in most cases.  My primary development environment is Windows.  However on Windows using Visual Studio, I want to build cross-platform C++ libraries that I can then package and ship for multiple platforms.  Is there anyway (some tool etc.) using which I can generate CMake configuration file (CMakeList.txt) for my Visual Studio C++ Library project?

Comment: Did you make any searches? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373158/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-cmakelist-txt-from-a-visual-studio-c-solution/14374515#14374515

Comment: Note that in general maintaining a cross-platform build environment is a complex endeavor. While automated conversion tools can be a good place to get started, they break down quickly once your project exceeds a certain complexity.

Comment: I have tried these many times but always ended up manually creating CMakeLists.txt for the project. The main reason is (for the ones that work) the ugly CMakeLists.txt that these produce that are littered with a lot of compiler compatibility settings macros ... that make it harder to use in a cross platform way.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

vcproj2cmake seems to be the answer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcproj2cmake/

Comment: vcproj2cmake is too heavily focused on being a continual use tool rather than a one-time converter.